# NSSortDescriptor to-many relationships

Tags: iphone, objective-c, one-to-many, nssortdescriptor

I use Core Data database.
I have Entity Album, that has many entities SpecificImage (key to get set of these images is @"specificImages")
I want to get Album with id = 1 and to sort attached SpecificImages by id.
I tried

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"specificImages.id" ascending:YES];
```

but I get the error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'

Here is my code:

```
    NSString *entityName = kEntityName;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesctiption = [NSEntityDescription 
                                              entityForName: entityName
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // find object
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %d", CurrentCategoryItemID];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"specificImages.id" ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    [request setEntity:entityDesctiption];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    [request release];
    if (objects == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"there was an error");
        return;
    }
    else if ([objects count] == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    NSManagedObject *object = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
```

it throws an exception, when I try to execute NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming, if you have many SpecificImages in Album then you will also have an inverse relationship from SpecificImage to Album ( 1 Album object in SpecificImage ).

Here I am first finding all SpecificImages for the required album id rather than all Albums and in the end form one of those SpecificImage object I will get the album object back.

```
NSString *entityName = @"SpecificImage";
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSEntityDescription *entityDesctiption = [NSEntityDescription 
                                          entityForName: entityName
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];

// find object
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"album.id == %d", CurrentCategoryItemID];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[request setEntity:entityDesctiption];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *specificImagesArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
[request release];
if (objects == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"there was an error");
    return;
}
else if ([objects count] == 0)
{
    return;
}
Album *album = [(SpecificImage *)[specificImagesArray objectAtIndex:0] album];
```

The specificImagesArray is the array of specificImages you are looking for and album is your required album with id = CurrentCategoryItemID.

Comment: I wanna sort attached images, but not to sort images and then return their album. So I should use something like [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"specificImages.id" ascending:YES];

Comment: specificimages is a nsset object.. so there is no id in it.. and adding a sortdescriptor in fetchRequest sorts the resultant array by comparing value of th key in all the resultant objects..

Comment: what i have done is the best possible solution for ur problem.. there is one more less efficient solution.. that would not include any sortdescriptors in fetchRequest.. alternatively you fetch the album you want and then access its specifcimages nsset and sort the values to ur desire

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is no any variant, how to do this. I had this problem. But I had to sord it by id after executing fetch request.