# Core Data. Sort NSMutableSet of big size NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, sorting, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

I want to fetch about 200 NSManagedObject, size of each is about 5Mb. If I use executeFetchRequest, I get  memory warning and app crashes (because fetched NSManagedObjects appears in the RAM of iPhone). If I can use executeFetchRequest, I can use sortdescriptor to sort data by id. But I can't (or may be I should set proper properties to NSFetchRequest, but I don't know, what properties).
That's why I used another approach to load big amount of data:
I have Entity Album, that has many entities SpecificImage. And I use this code to fetch all images of current album:

```
- (NSMutableSet *)getAllSpecificImages
{
        NSString *entityName = kEntityName;
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
        NSEntityDescription *entityDesctiption = [NSEntityDescription 
                                                  entityForName: entityName
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
        // check if town exists
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %d", self.CurrentCategoryItemID];
        NSFetchRequest *requestToCheckExistense = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [requestToCheckExistense setEntity:entityDesctiption];
        [requestToCheckExistense setPredicate:predicate];
        NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:requestToCheckExistense error:nil];
        [requestToCheckExistense release];
        if (objects == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"there was an error");
            return nil;
        }
        NSManagedObject *object;
        if ([objects count] > 0)
        {
            // edit item
            object = [objects objectAtIndex:0];

        }
        else
        {
            // if object doesn't exist, find max id to imlement autoincrement
            NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            [request setEntity:entityDesctiption];
            NSArray *allobjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
            [request release];
            NSInteger newID = 1;
            if ([allobjects count] > 0)
            {
                NSNumber *maxID = [allobjects valueForKeyPath:@"@max.id"];
                newID = [maxID intValue] + 1;
            }

            // write item
            object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
            [object setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newID] forKey:@"id"];
            self.CurrentCategoryItemID = newID;
        }

    NSMutableSet *set = [object mutableSetValueForKey:@"specificImages"];
    return set;
}
```

then I get array of NSManagedObjects

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[setOfManagedObjectsSpecificImages allObjects]];
```

but then I try to get sorted array of this NSManagedObjects and I again get  memory warning and app crashes.
I tried to use

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDiscriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
[array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDiscriptor]];
```

and

```
[self quickSort:array left:0 right:([array count] - 1)];
```

where

```
- (void)quickSort: (NSMutableArray *)arr left:(NSInteger)left right:(NSInteger) right
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int i = left, j = right;

        int pivot = [((SpecificImage *)[arr objectAtIndex:(left + right) / 2]).id intValue];



        /* partition */

        while (i <= j) {
            while ([((SpecificImage *)[arr objectAtIndex:i]).id intValue] < pivot)
            {

                i++;
            }

            while ([((SpecificImage *)[arr objectAtIndex:j]).id intValue] > pivot)
            {

                j--;
            }

            if (i <= j) {

                [arr exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];

                i++;

                j--;

            }

        };


        /* recursion */

        if (left < j)
        {
            [self quickSort:arr left:left right:j];
        }

        if (i < right)
        {
            [self quickSort:arr left:i right:right];
        }

    }

}
```

but that didn't help.

From my perspective, when I get a set of NSManagedObjects, they are not in the RAM. But during sorting they appears in the RAM.

I wanted to get sorted NSMutableSet (tried to set :

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"specificImages.id" ascending:YES];
```

But I got

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
```

I described this issue is the other question [NSSortDescriptor to-many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813826/nssortdescriptor-to-many-relationships)

From my point of view, I see 2 approaches:
1) executeFetchRequest, but provide: the objects don't appear in the RAM ( I don't know how, but I'm almost shure that it's possible)
2) change my quick sort to provide: the objects don't appear in the RAM

**Update**
Here is my code, where I try to fetch objects with executeFetchRequest (the objects are in RAM and I want it to be fault objects (not in the RAM)):

```
+ (NSMutableSet *)GetImagesWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
{
    NSString *entityName = kEntityName;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesctiption = [NSEntityDescription 
                                              entityForName: entityName
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // find object
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesctiption];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    [request release];
    if (objects == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"there was an error");
        return nil;
    }
    NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:objects];
    return set;
}
```

where predicate:

```
NSMutableArray *allID = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 1; i < 639; i++)
{
      [allID addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id in %@", allID];
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you shouldn't be storing 5MB of data in a single entity/row. The Apple guidelines explicitly talk about this. Images, unless they are very small, should be stored on the file system and only their path stored in the entity.

Comment: can you proved a link to Apple guidelines explicitly. So I can read it. (I heared about this, but I want to read it by myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr the code.

CoreData has a thing. It's called **faulting**. Fault object means that you have references to that object who's data is still in the store (your version of "not in RAM"). To de'fault an object you'd have to call `valueForKey:` method and fetch any property (this loads the whole object except for relationships). When doing sorting, core data internally calls `valueForKey:` which causes your image data to get loaded.

My proposal for you: create a separate entity called something like `ImageDescriptor` where you'd hold all the properties required for sorting. This entity would hold one-to-one relationship to actual binary image data which you would fetch only when needed (i.e. use lazy fetching).

Comment: Good idea, but I hope, may be there is any other approach: 1) hide all the data again, after I used valueForKey: 2) to executeFetchRequest with Fault objects (that are not in the RAM)

Comment: 1) you can't fault an object in the middle of sorting (this requires calling `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` method call for each object on the context you're fetching objects from. 2) AFAIK - `executeFetchRequest:` retrieves faulted objects by default.

Comment: if executeFetchRequest: retrieves faulted objects by default, why does the app get memory warning. I will updata the question for you. I will add the code with executeFetchRequest:

Comment: You may try simplifying the predicate. Array with 600 objects can be presented in a different way (`id < 689`). You can also try setting the fetch limit with sort descriptors. This way you'd get sorted results, but not the whole batch, but part of it.

Comment: 1) id can different, id < 689 - it's only for test, that why I need to use (id in array); 2) I should get all the data, and as I know I can't get portions of sorted data. It seems to me , that if I specify limit, I will always get only first results

Comment: You must use `fetchOffset` with `fetchLimit` to get pagination effect for your fetched results.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanna get the entire array of objects. I will try, may be with fetchLimit the objects will be fault.

Comment: Assuming you don't want to put the images on the file system, I agree you need a separate entity just for the image data. Then you can easily load and sort the parent entities without running into problems.

Comment: I used fetchLimit, but objects are not fualt still. And app crashes. I agree with Eimantas, that it's possible to create a separate entity just for the image data. But I still wanna get faulted objects using  executeFetchRequest, because I think , that I should change only some properties of the request to provide this.

Comment: I decided, that if nobody answers me up to tomorrow about executeFetchRequest with fault objects , I will accept your answer and will use your approach

Answer (score 0):

I used Eimantas approach, but I got how to fetch objects withous recording them in RAM.
I used `includesPropertyValues`